# How to store filename into a variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I want to store the filename (which is in the Excel connection manager) into a variable.

Then the same variable I need to pass as an input parameter to a stored procedure in order to execute the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the connection string is hardcoded in the Excel connection manager. I would suggest doing it vice versa. Create a variable and set the file name (connection string) in that variable. Then right-click on the connection manager and find the Expressions property. Click on the three dots. It will open a dialog where you can choose ExcelFilePath and set it to your variable. Then you can use this variable as an input variable in your stored procedure.

This way you could pass any valid file path to the variable and this way maintain it dynamically.

Please let me know if this helps.

[Excel Connection Manager - Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAgMa.png)